# Python Dataframe set value by position and not Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cell

[What I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2UpZ.png)

[image: so far]

So I'm trying to change a single cell in an `dataframe` but by using `set_value` I can't use the position and need to use the index and if I got two equal indexes it will change both.

How can I change a single cell avoiding this?
Thank you,

Comment: `df=df.reset_index()`

Comment: please do not use images, if you copy and paste code it can be executed by us.

Comment: Thanks, will not do from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set by position, use `.iloc`, e.g.

```
df.iloc[0,0] = 2.
```

This modifies your dataframe in-place.

Comment: I think I was doing some mistake when I was trying to use `iloc` but you are right, it worked, thanks;